# Element wise multiplication of decision variable array and list of integers in python RSOME

Tags: python, optimization, elementwise-operations, decision-model-notation

I have a decision variable array and I want to multiply each decision variable with a different integer of a list
Here is an example:

```
#Import libraries
from rsome import ro
m=3
a = [0.10,0.1,1] 
b = [0.13,0.1,0.3]
#create a model object
model = ro.Model('model')
x = model.dvar(m) #array of decision variables               
y = model.dvar(m) #array of decision variables

#objective function
model.min(((a*x)- (b*y)).sum())
```

My question is how do I make sure this operation is actually doing an element wise multiplication ?
When I check type of x or y type I get I get 3 continuous variables and
PriceImp*Pimp is 1x3 affine expressions but is it element wise multiplication?

Comment: I am not sure if this is necessary, but in rsome examples I see they use `np.arrays`, not lists

Comment: I used the arrays instead and I am getting the same optimization result which most probably means it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade RSOME to the latest version, and make sure that coefficients like `a` and `b` are defined as `np.ndarray` type objects, instead of lists.

The `*` operator performs element-wise multiplication, so `a*x` and `b*y` should be "3 affine expressions". RSOME also supports broadcasting, just like NumPy, so if a 1x3 coefficient array times an array of 3 variables, the shape of the affine expression is 1x3.